# how to call remote datasource in jquery autocomplete?

Tags: jquery, jquery-autocomplete

I have a action file having data in json format.I am trying to implement autocomplete in jquery ajax.In the ajax call,can anybdy help me in calling that action class containing json data,required in jquery autocomplete .the way I m doing it is as follows,I m unable to call action class in url

```
$.ajax(){
    type: "POST",
    url:
    dataType: "json",
    data: {},
    contentType: "application\json;charset=utf-8",
    success: function(response) {
        var dataFromServer=eval('('+jqxhr.responseText+')');
        $.autocomplete({
            source:dataFromServer
        )};
    }
    error: function(XMLHttpRequest,textStatus,errorThrown){
        alert(textStatus);
    }
```

Comment: Please format your code so that others can read it. You have some syntax error in your code, I suggest you fix them first. Otherwise we don't know what is the real problem or what is just sloppiness.

Answer (score 0):

```
$.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "",
            dataType: "json",
            data: "{}",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            success: function(response) {

                var datafromServer = eval('('+jqXHR.responseText+')');

                $("#id").autocomplete({
                    source: datafromServer
                });

            },
            error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {

               alert(textStatus);
            }
        });
```